# Select non-null rows from a specific column in a DataFrame and take a sub-selection of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, nan

I have a dataframe which has several columns, so I chose some of its columns to create a variable like this.

```py
xtrain = df[['Age', 'Fare', 'Group_Size', 'deck', 'Pclass', 'Title']]
```

I want to drop from these columns all rows where the `Survive` column in the main dataframe is `nan`.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49673345/6064933

Answer (score 60, accepted):

You can pass a boolean mask to your df based on [`notnull()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.notnull.html) of 'Survive' column and select the cols of interest:

```
In [2]:
# make some data
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(5,7), columns= ['Survive', 'Age','Fare', 'Group_Size','deck', 'Pclass', 'Title' ])
df['Survive'].iloc[2] = np.NaN
df
Out[2]:
    Survive       Age      Fare  Group_Size      deck    Pclass     Title
0  1.174206 -0.056846  0.454437    0.496695  1.401509 -2.078731 -1.024832
1  0.036843  1.060134  0.770625   -0.114912  0.118991 -0.317909  0.061022
2       NaN -0.132394 -0.236904   -0.324087  0.570660  0.758084 -0.176421
3 -2.145934 -0.020003 -0.777785    0.835467  1.498284 -1.371325  0.661991
4 -0.197144 -0.089806 -0.706548    1.621260  1.754292  0.725897  0.860482
```

Now pass a mask to [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-label) to take only non `NaN` rows:

```
In [3]:
xtrain = df.loc[df['Survive'].notnull(), ['Age','Fare', 'Group_Size','deck', 'Pclass', 'Title' ]]
xtrain

Out[3]:
        Age      Fare  Group_Size      deck    Pclass     Title
0 -0.056846  0.454437    0.496695  1.401509 -2.078731 -1.024832
1  1.060134  0.770625   -0.114912  0.118991 -0.317909  0.061022
3 -0.020003 -0.777785    0.835467  1.498284 -1.371325  0.661991
4 -0.089806 -0.706548    1.621260  1.754292  0.725897  0.860482
```

Comment: Just wish to know why the 'Survive' column is completely off in the output? The question asks for dropping all rows that have NaNs, not the entire columns that may have one or more NaNs.

Comment: @MuneshSingh the original question asked for an output with these columns ['Age', 'Fare', 'Group_Size', 'deck', 'Pclass', 'Title'] (the OP explained the "Survive" column was in the original data, but not requested in the output). The "Survive" column is not included in the output bc it is not in the 'columns_indexer' list in the `.loc` call. i.e. `df.loc[row_indexer, column_indexer]`. See https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#different-choices-for-indexing for a complete explanation.

Answer (score 10):

Two alternatives because... well why not?
Both drop `nan` prior to column slicing.  That's two call rather than EdChum's one call.

***one***

```
df.dropna(subset=['Survive'])[
    ['Age','Fare', 'Group_Size','deck', 'Pclass', 'Title' ]]
```

***two***

```
df.query('Survive == Survive')[
    ['Age','Fare', 'Group_Size','deck', 'Pclass', 'Title' ]]
```

Comment: df.dropna(subset=['Survive'])[['Survive','Age','Fare', 'Group_Size','deck', 'PCLass', 'Title' ]]  will retain the 'Survive' column too.

Answer (score 0):

It might be more readable if you assign the subset of the columns to a variable and filter.

```py
notna_msk = df['Survive'].notna()
cols = ['Age', 'Fare', 'Group_Size', 'deck', 'Pclass', 'Title', 'Survive']
new_df = df.loc[notna_msk, cols]
```

Also, in case you already created `xtrain` from `df` as in the OP, then you can still filter this dataframe with the mask, even if it doesn't have `Survive` column; just the index is enough.

```py
new_df = xtrain.loc[df['Survive'].notna()]
```