# Python Pandas: get rows of a DataFrame where a column is not null

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm filtering my DataFrame dropping those rows in which the cell value of a specific column is None.

```
df = df[df['my_col'].isnull() == False]
```

Works fine, but PyCharm tells me:

> PEP8: comparison to False should be 'if cond is False:' or 'if not cond:'

But I wonder how I should apply this to my use-case? Using 'not ...' or ' is False' did not work. My current solution is:

```
df = df[df['my_col'].notnull()]
```

Comment: `df = df[df['my_col'].notnull()]` ?

Comment: `~` is the not operator

Comment: `df = df[not df['my_col'].isnull()]` ?

Comment: Still I wonder how this is related to the PEP8 message.

Comment: @MohammadAthar that doesn't work. As mentioned in my question.

Comment: @Matthias, i agree with PEP8 - it doesn't look Pythonic or Pandaic (Pandas has boolean indexing and negation operator `~`)...

Comment: `df = df.dropna(subset=['my_col'])`

Comment: PEP8 cannot apply here. You are comparing a Series against a single value. You don't have a scalar. If you want to get rid of it, you can just use `df['my_col'].notnull()` though.

Comment: @jezrael that is definitely not the same question. This should not have been closed for that reason.

Comment: @FHTMitchell - So sorry, reopened.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

So python has the short-circuiting logic operators `not`, `and`, `or`. These have a very specific meaning in python and cannot be overridden (`not` must return a `bool` and `a and/or b` always returns either `a` or `b` or throws an error.

However, python also has over-loadable boolean operators `~` (not), `&` (and), `|` (or) and `^` (xor).

You may recognise these as the `int` bitwise operators, but Numpy (and therefore pandas) use these to do array / series boolean operations.

For example

```
b = np.array([True, False, True]) & np.array([True, False, False])
# b --> [True False False]
b = ~b 
# b --> [False True True]
```

Hence what you want is

```
df = df[~df['my_col'].isnull()]
```

I agree with PEP8, don't do `== False`.

Comment: Thanks for the explantation and yet another example.